# Why Rails dont recognize route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have in routes.rb

```
get '/cities/:city/:section'  => 'cities#show',  as: 'city_section_slug'
get '/cities/:city/:section/:subsection'   => 'cities#show', as: 'city_subsection_slug', :constraints => { :subsection => /[^\/]*/ }
```

And rake show these routes

```
city_section_slug GET        (/:locale)/cities/:city_id/:section(.:format)                  cities#show {:locale=>/ru|en/}
city_subsection_slug GET        (/:locale)/cities/:city_id/:section/:subsection(.:format)      cities#show {:subsection=>/[^\/]*/, :locale=>/ru|en/}
```

But when I try create a link:

```
= link_to city_subsection_slug_path(@city,section.alias, subsection.alias)
```

Iv got such error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"cities", :action=>"show", :locale=>:ru, :city=>#<City id: 42, name: "City">, :section=>"events", :subsection=>"sobytiya/ya-ochevidets"}):
```

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your constraint on subsection param. You specified that it can be anything as long as it does not contain `/` character. Your subsection does conatin it hence the error. If you want to allow `/` character, then do:

```
get '/cities/:city/:section/:subsection' => 'cities#show',
       as: 'city_subsection_slug',
       constraints: { :subsection => /^[a-z0-9_\/]+$/ }
```

Eventually, you can use glob param:

```
get '/cities/:city/:section/*subsection' => 'cities#show',
       as: 'city_subsection_slug',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cities, only: [] do
  get ":section", action: :show, as: :city_section_slug                #-> url.com/cities/:city_id/:section
  get ":section/*subsection", action: :show, as: :city_subsection_slug #-> url.com/cities/:city_id/:section/:subsection
end
```

The corresponding links:

```
<%= link_to "x", city_section_slug_path(@city, section.alias) %>
<%= link_to "x", city_subsection_slug_path(@city, section.alias, subsection.alias) %>
```

---

**Wildcard**

If you're expecting to send `sobytiya/ya-ochevidets` to your `subsection` path, you'll be best using a [wildcard](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) route

Comment: Can you explain how the generated urls will contain `:city_id` without providing it in the route?

Comment: [Extra routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) -- `You can leave out the :on option, this will create the same member route except that the resource id value will be available in params[:photo_id] instead of params[:id].`

Comment: But the routes which are nested are not resourceful. Is nested resources concept works on non-resourceful routes as well?

Comment: Sorry I was trigger happy, it's not about nested resources; it's just adding extra routes for the `cities` resource